# how to build a chain of calls render itemViews in marrionete.js deferred with async function inside itemView

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, marionette, deferred

I have a very simple structure

```
ProductsList.TileListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'section',
    className: 'b-list-viewtile',
    template: '/static/js/app/list/modules/productslist/templates/tileList',
    childView: ProductsList.TileItemView

});



ProductsList.TileItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "article",
    className: "b-list-viewtile__item",
    template:  '/static/js/app/list/modules/productslist/templates/tileItem',
    _getImage: function(){

        var _this = this;

        var img =  new Image();
        img.src = this.model.get("media");
        img.onload = function(){
            msnry.append( _this.$el )
                .masonry( 'appended', _this.$el ).masonry('layout');
        };
    }
});
```

but I use the Masonry plugin to align items on grid.

The problem is that for each item I need to know the value of a variable such as the height of the image.

that means build each itemView i can only previous item appended in DOM.

Also important to maintain order in the collection - the first in the collection should be rendered first etc.

Spent a lot of time to study the documentation but have not found an elegant solution

Can anybody tell how to build that "chain"? every item must wait render previous, but final result order must stay as in collection, not in image load priority.

I think it smthg about deffered+marrionette.callback and override native attachHtml or buildChildView

thx a lot:)

Comment: Are you OK using ES6 promises or do you have a preferred Promises library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're going to use Marionette's built in Marionette.Babysitter and ES6 Promises to solve your problem.

If you read the [docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-resortview) carefully (or thumb through the source) you'll learn that Marionette renders child views in collection order.

> By default the `CollectionView` will maintain the order of its `collection`
> in the DOM.

Additionally, all CollectionViews will also hold a reference to all of its children views, in the order they were rendered, which, again is in their collection sort order.

What you want is to ensure that all children views have been rendered, and then to add that child view `el` to your Masonry item list, *in order*.

### First, set up your Promises

We'll modify your children view's `._getImage` method slightly, and allow it to return a Promise:

```
_getImage: function(){
    var _this = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var img =  new Image();
      img.src = this.model.get("media");
      img.onload = function(){
          resolve();
      };
    });
}
```

When the image of this arbitrary child view is loaded the promise returned by getImage will be resolved. How does this help us? Read on.

### Second, wait until all of your images are loaded

In your CollectionView you'll add this property, `onRenderCollection`, which is fired by Marionette when all your children views have finished rendering. Here, using Babysitter, we'll fire the `_getImage` method of your children views, and set up the Masonry promise chain you were looking for.

```
onRenderCollection: function () {
  var promises = [];
  this.children.each(function (childview) {
    promises.push(childview._getImage()); // return the promise
  })
  // When all your children view's images have loaded we begin to fill Masonry
  Promise.all(promises).then(_.bind(function () {
    this.children.each(function (childview) {
      childview.addToMasonry();
    }
  }, this))
}
```

### Third, add to Masonry!

Of course we don't yet have a property named `addToMasonry` on your children views, but I assume you'll use one that looks a lot like what you had on your `img.onload` callback. Something like this

```
addToMasonry: function () {
  masonry.append( this.$el )
    .masonry( 'appended', this.$el ).masonry('layout');
}
```

### Drawback

The one caveat with this method is that you first have to wait until all the children views are rendered. If the list is very long (thousand+), this could be a performance issue, and a workaround may not be trivial.

Comment: thanks a lot.  

This is almost what I need, except that render comes after all the promises. 
if render one by one is not trivial case - i think, it will good decision because number of pieces in the collections of less than 20.
It deals only smoothe each fadeIn.

But i have a one question. 

How can i catch childview with their methods in this code example?
childview there is instance of Promise

Comment: `Promise.all(promises).then(function (childview) {
    childview.addToMasonry();
})`

Comment: Good catch. Please see the edit to the answer. And take note of how the handler is bound to the CollectionView context using underscore's `_.bind()`.